# how to manage concurrent connections to sftp from function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, sftp, azure-blob-storage, ssh.net

**How do we manage concurrent connections, perhaps by batching the files into the same connection?**

I'm creating an azure function to be triggered by new blobs (this might be changed to a simple timer-trigger). An example of a blob would be:

```
{
"server":"sftp.mysftpserver.com",
"credentials":"topsecret",
"body":"This text will be uploaded to the sftp server above"
}
```

The function will login to the server, and send the payload in the `body`.

**How do we limit the number of connections that are being initiated to the same server?**

We might have 500 blobs that are all triggering the function, which in turn is opening 500 connections to: `sftp.mysftpserver.com`.

At the same time there might be just 2 blobs that are initiating connections to `sftp.otherserver.net`.

Comment: get a queue server to manage which one can go next?

Comment: not sure i understand your question, @Steve

Comment: @itsme86 its fake

Answer (score -1):

Without more info on the specific implementation I can only give general advice. Assuming you are using some sort of FTP client, you can use a [static instance of that client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale) to share it within a Functions instance. If throughput is that high then the Functions service will scale to multiple instances, but assuming you are on the consumption plan this will [max out at 200](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale). Unless there is a huge bottleneck, the a 500 document spike would likely be cleared before the scaling got anywhere near 200 instances.

For example you would do something like this:

```
// Create a single, static SftpClient
private static SftpClient client = new sftpClient(endpoint, user, pass);

public static async Task Run(string input)
{
    var response = await sftpClient.SendAsync("filename.txt", input);
}
```

If you aren't using an SFTP library that can do this by default, you can create a static helper class that handles creating the client.

Comment: i wouldnt want to share a client among multiple instances, i want a new client each time because i have no way of knowing if i would be using the same credentials/connection for any given connection. every instance should have its own client

Comment: If you do 1 client per instance than on the consumption plan your limit will be 1200 external connections across all instances. If you use an App Service plan than you can have more control over the number of instances but you loose the scaling and pricing advantages of the consumption plan. Using a timer trigger limits you to a single instance- batching like that would help in this case where you have many different connections as long as you can complete processing within the timeout (10 minutes for consumption).

Comment: how would you pass these variables in: `endpoint`, `user`, `pass` ? using DI or something?

Comment: Usually you would use App Settings. If you are concerned about security, you can make use of Key Vault and then use those references as the settings instead of the actual username and password. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Comment: Each execution of the function represents a different SFTP server

Comment: Good point- it's been awhile since we talked about this and I skimmed over the details a bit too quickly. 

I'm not aware of any libraries that do this so you might need to roll your own class, but I think that leveraging .NET Core DI would be the way to go to control the connection count. Instead of the static class being the client, have the static class be something that holds a single client for each server and allows you to request a specific one or open a new connection and store it if it isn't already there.

Comment: Implementation details would of course depend on how you coded it, but essentially I would inject that static class (IoC, Factory, whatever pattern you want to call it) and then have a method for requesting the correct client once I'm inside the context of a specific function run and know which one I need for it.

Comment: Can a durable entity cache the static client?